# How frightened should I be by this MacOS Keychain Access error?

Tags: macos, keychain, keychain-access

```
Keychain Access - Unexpected Error

An unexpected error has occurred that may cause
Keychain Access to malfunction. You may want to quit
the Keychain Access application.

Error: *** -[NSIndexSet initWithIndexesInRange:]:
Range {9223373036854775807, 1} exceeds maximum
index value of NSNotFound - 1
```

[image: Keychain Error]

Comment: Your level of fear ought to be directly proportionate to the length of time since your last backup.

Comment: And, of-course the value of the keys and difficulty replacing them)

Comment: Do you suspect hacking?

Comment: I suspect data corruption somewhere. Run the standard disk tests. You'll still probably have to recover the keychain from your backup.